# devise resource.errors.any? not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

View.html.erb below:

```
<div id="flash">

 <% if resource.errors.any? %>
 <div id="error_explanation" class="error">
 <h2>Hold on!</h2>
    <ul>
        <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
            <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
    </ul>
 </div>
 <% end %>

 <% flash.each do |type, message| %>
 <div class="<%= twitterized_type(type) %> alert alert-dismissable"></div>
 <button aria-hidden="true" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"></button>
 <p>
 <%= message %>
</p>
<% end %>
</div>
```

The routes file follows:

```
 get '/privacy'  => 'high_voltage/pages#show', id: 'privacy'
 get '/terms'    => 'high_voltage/pages#show', id: 'terms'

 get '/home', to: redirect('/') 

 root :to => 'high_voltage/pages#show', id: 'home'
```

The flash part of the error processing is working, The resources.errors.any part does not 
show any errors when there are sign in errors!

Comment: What’s in your controller?

Comment: Why not use `@user.errors.any?`?

Comment: class PagesController < ApplicationController
    def new
    
    end
   end

Comment: Using @user.errors.any? gives no method error HighVoltageShoe#pages

Comment: If there’s nothing in the controller, where does `resource` come from?

Comment: resources :users, :only => [:new] this is whatI used in the routes

Comment: Have you not tried the [`devise_error_messages!`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/Override-devise_error_messages!-for-views) helper?

Comment: Yes, I did use a helper in app/helpers/devise_helper.rb, but that did not help either, this method was overridden in this helper, ie I have my own devise_error_messages! method in the helper: devise_helper.rb- this did not help either. If I remove the code fragment with resource.errors.any? the code executes the flash message|key, value| alright, I was wondering why the code fragment in resource.errors.any? did not work.